# Checkout/Fetch/Clone/etc. a single commit from multiple remotes?

Tags: git, optimization, continuous-integration

tl;dr; Is there a way to create a shallow git clone of a remote repo from one (slow) URL while using other (faster) URLs to grab anything that's already available there?

*Edit:* BTW All the terms I could think of to search for this came up blank. Answers of the form "It's called `[fill in the blank]`" would be as welcome as anything else.

---

Background is that I'm trying to get my CI to run faster. One of the expensive steps (in some cases >90% of the run time) is fetching all the dependencies over the internet from different repos. This is annoying because I already have (or could have) all those repos cloned locally and having it fetch from there would be way faster. In principle, this should be totally viable by just treating the fast local repos as look-aside-caches that are inspected before the slow remote is queried, but that would likely require open-heart surgery on git to implement and I don't have the resource to dig into that.

---

The problem with doing this via the well know parts of the public interface is two fold.

1. I need the exact same build operation to work with or without the local set of repos. Anything more than "BTW: here is a (possibly empty) list of repos you should look in first" is non-viable.
2. The local repos might not be *exactly* up to date. They will have most of the relevant history, but might not have the exact commit needed.

Issue #1 might be something that could be solved by adding each of the look-aside-URLs as a remote and attempting to do a shallow clone from each in turn. But if none of them have the exact commit needed, then everything gets downloaded from the last (and slowest) URL even if the others have most of what is need.

Another option would be to do a full local clone of one of the fast URLs (they are all on the same file system in my specific case, but that doesn't generalize) so that everything is just hard links and then fetch in the slow remote to get get anything else that's missing. But that only works for the first remote because add-remote + fetch doesn't hardlink things making that a deep copy (there is no way to know in advance what is needed).

Answer (score 1):

We use 2 methods to deal with similar issues. Not sure if they can solve your issue, but I think they could give a clue on it.

One is `--reference[-if-able] <repository>` of `git clone`. It reuses the existing objects in the reference repository for a new clone. With the help of `--depth <depth>` and `--single-branch -b <branch/tag>`, the new clone fetches objects as less as possible. The reference repository is updated at regular intervals. The more it holds, the less the new clone fetches.

The other is maintaining a local non-bare and no-checkout repository created by `git clone --no-checkout <url>`. When we need to checkout a commit, first we fetch the ref that contains the commit, and then creates a linked worktree for the commit by `git worktree add /path/to/worktree <commit>`. In some cases, `git sparse-checkout` is also used to save space of the checkout.

These methods reuse the existing data as much as possible, saving the cost of both time and space and allowing multiple jobs to run parallelly.

Comment: `--reference[-if-able]` (and maybe `--dissociate`) may be exactly what I'm looking for.